# Where to place config files in JARs?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, slf4j, manifest.mf

My JAR currently has the following structure:

```
myapp.jar
    META-INF
        MANIFEST.MF
    net
        myapp
            MyAppDriver.class (fully qualified as net.myapp.MyAppDriver)
            <lots of other classes>
```

My app requires the need to read a file from the runtime classpath, and configure itself based on the contents of the file (`simplelogger.properties` from the SLF4J framework).

**Where do I place `simplelogger.properties` in the JAR? Do I need to set anything inside `MANFIEST.MF` as well?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to put your config file near jar file. But it would be better if you can put it inside jar file

Comment: Thanks @AlekseiBulgak (+1) - **where inside the JAR?**  At the root of the JAR (at same level as `META-INF` and `net` package)? Somewhere else? Thanks again!

Comment: at same level as META-INF

Comment: Ahhh, thanks again @AlekseiBulgak - so to confirm: my JAR should have 3 top-level items: (1) simplelogger.properties, (2) net and (3) META-INF? Thanks again!

Comment: yes, if this is not a web application

Answer (score 0):

You can place the file in any JAR anywhere you would like. If you want it to live alongside `MyAppDriver.class`, for example, you could then call `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("net/myapp/simplelogger.properties")` to get an `InputStream` to that file. You don't need a manifest for this to work.